# HTTPS communication without requesting certificate

Tags: encryption, ssl, https, tls, cryptography

Is there a hack or the architecture of SSL/TLS allows communication with a Server without requesting it's certificate may be by pre downloading the certificate and installing it,
The reason I'm asking this is because during the handshake process, the SNI extension exposes the website I'm communicating with since SNI sends the domain name in plain text...
I've tried using older versions of SSL where there was no SNI but most servers don't support older version of SSL...

Answer (score 2):

You're asking about two different things: hostname leaks by the client sending SNI, and hostname leaks by the server sending a certificate. These are **completely independent** from each other; SNI does not force a certificate to be sent, and disabling SNI won't prevent a certificate from being sent.

#### Client to server

> during the handshake process, the SNI extension exposes the website I'm communicating with

If you're communicating with *your own* servers, then just don't send the SNI extension. It is optional in most TLS client libraries. (For example, in GnuTLS it is not sent by default, *unless* gnutls_server_name_set() was called.)

On the other hand, for random websites on the Internet, it is often unavoidable.

#### Server to client

> Is there a hack or the architecture of SSL/TLS allows communication with a Server without requesting it's certificate

TLS supports other methods of server authentication – TLS-PSK is the most common alternative (though generally it only works with servers that you've pre-configured with the shared key; not random websites on the internet).

Alternatively, the certificate could contain a random hostname or no hostname at all, and the client would verify it using other methods (by fingerprint or SPKI hash) – TLS does not require the use of a hostname at all.